# How window 64 bit affect a java developer and what does it mean in general?

Tags: java, windows, operating-system

As most of the new laptops are coming with 64 bit window OS. **My question is how does it impact to java developer when he is migrating from 32 bit OS to 64 bit OS?** Another question is i have heard people saying with 64 bit OS can support more RAM than 32 bit. **I dont know the logic behind it?** Some time people also say with 64 bit OS it can support 64 bit address which was not there in 32 bit OS. **If it is true how earlier 64 bit long was supported in java in 32 bit OS?**

Comment: A data type is unrelated to the size of a cpu's memory bus; same reason we could do 32-bit math on an 8-bit processor.

Comment: 64-bit `long` refers to the size of the long, it is unrelated to the addressable size of memory, which can be simplified to how many 'slots' there are. There are 2^32 and 2^64 slots in 32-bit and 64-bit address space respectively. This is extremely simplified, but you should hopefully appreciate that 'things' (primitives such as `long` or `Class` types) take up more than one 'slot'.

Comment: Thanks Dough for the clarification. But can you give two line brief how 64 bit support more RAM than 32 bit and how 64 bit OS helps to end user? Yes i got the point with 64 bit , OS can get hold of more addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't effect the average Java developer as it pertains to the code he writes. Java is designed to work the same on all operating systems. So if there's a JVM for Windows 64 bit (which I'm sure there is) then it's all good.

Now, there is a chance for bugs in the 64 bit JVM that do not exist in other JVMs, but those will not effect most developers and are typically quickly fixed.

Also, if you have JNI code you will have to adapt that, but again *most* Java developers have nothing to fear.